# How to determine what is generating large amount of database queries?

Tags: plugins, database, mysql

For some reason, my Wordpress site is using a lot of memory (spiking at 72MB) and generating a huge amount of database queries (76923 according to Wp-Memory-Usage. I'm really not sure why this would be, as there is nothing going on on the site that would create these. The only thing I can think of is the Ninja Forms plugin.

The site is here: http://cbipath.com

And the plugins installed are:

BlackStudio TinyMCE
Easy Bootstrap Shortcodes
Ninja Forms
Shortcodes Ultimate
Page Builder by SiteOrigin
TPC Memory Usage
WP-Pro-Quiz
Plugin Performance Profiler

I have a plugin load time of .449 sec per visit, Plugin impact of 58.8% of page load time, and 98 MySQL queries per visit (all according to the Plugin Performance Profiler).

Any insight would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Query Monitor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin

**From Plugin Documention:**

Here's an overview of what's shown:

> **Database Queries**
>
> 1. Shows all database queries performed on the current page
> 2. Shows affected rows and time for all queries
> 3. Show notifications for slow queries and queries with errors
> 4. Filter queries by query type (SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc)
> 5. Filter queries by component (WordPress core, Plugin X, Plugin Y, theme)
> 6. Filter queries by calling function
> 7. View aggregate query information grouped by component, calling function, and type
> 8. Super advanced: Supports multiple instances of wpdb on one page
>
> Filtering queries by component or calling function makes it easy to
>   see which plugins, themes, or functions on your site are making the
>   most (or the slowest) database queries.